# iOS 16 Poor SpeechSynthesisUtterance voice quality

Tags: iphone, safari, speech-synthesis, ios16, webspeech-api

since iOS 16 update my vocabulary app (PWA) has problems with spelling provided text to `SpeechSynthesisUtterance` object. It doesn't apply to all languages, eg. Russian sounds the same like before update to iOS 16. If it comes to German or English - the quality is very low, muffled, the voice sounds nasal... For MacOS Safari everything works as supposed to, but not for iOS 16.

```
const fullPhrase = toFullPhrase(props.phrase);
const utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();

onMounted(() => { // Vue lifecycle method
  utterance.text = fullPhrase;
  utterance.lang = voice.value.lang;
  utterance.voice = voice.value;
  utterance.addEventListener(ON_SPEAK_END, toggleSpeakStatus);
});
```

I tried to modify `pitch` and `rate` properties but without success... Did they change API for `SpeechSynthesis` / `SpeechSynthesisUtterance` for Safari in iOS 16 maybe?

Comment: I have the same, what's strange Polish lang is ok, but English not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like IO16 introduced a lot of new (sometimes very weird) voices for en-GB and en-US. In my case I was looking for a voice only by a lang and taking the first one. As a result I was getting a strange voice.

Comment: You're right. I had to hardcode iOS voice names ('Daniel' for 'en-GB', 'Anna' for 'de-DE') and search for these voices specifically. Russian sounds OK because it has only one available (good) voice. Using the first found voice for EN/DE gives terrible result.

Comment: @chudy91 I try to "hardcode" Anna for 'de-DE'  but it's even not listed, although installed and available on the Accessibility page and system-level voice over. How is this available on your system?

Answer (score 2):

iOS 16 seems to have completely messed up voices for speechSynthesis.getVoices() at least for en-US lang. Before iOS 16, it used to display only two voices for en-US: Fred and Samantha. Regardless if you chose Fred or Samantha it would always use Samantha. Now, iOS 16 displays a bunch of new voices but none of them are the good sounding voices found in in Settings > Accessibility > VoiceOver > Speech > Voice. And "Samantha" is missing from getVoices(). Apple needs to fix this.

As a workaround you can get speechSynthesis.speak(utterance) to use "Samantha" or possibly what is default for the phone by not setting a voice with utterance.voice.